# DIVs not aligning properly in FireFox

Tags: css, html, alignment

The following HTML and CSS code lines up in IE, Chrome and Safari but it does not line up in FireFox.  What can I do to make it work in all four major browsers?

HTML:

```
<div id="subnav">
    <div id="subnavtab"><a href="">Plan Your Visit</a></div>
    <div id="subnavtab"><a href="">Tour the Museum</a></div>
    <div id="subnavtab"><a href="">Program & Events</a></div>
    <div id="subnavtab"><a href="">Membership</a></div>
    <div id="subnavtab"><a href="">Donate</a></div>
</div>
<div id="featuredexhibit">
    Featured Exhibit - this can be a rotating menu of exhibits
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#subnav { margin-top: 20px; width: 740px; text-align: center; }
.subnavtab { background-color: #A1CD3A; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; margin: 0 5px 0 0; display: inline-block; } 
#featuredexhibit { width: 740px; height: 200px; background-color: #A7A9AC; margin: 0; clear: both; }
```

Comment: You have the same **ID** multiple times. Use **class** instead.

Comment: in despite of your IDs problem like said Vucko all seems to be working fine on my Firefox and Chrome...
which version of firefox are you using?

Comment: It was using Firefox 10.0 but I just updated it to 19.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to use several times the same id (subnavtab). Use classes instead.

Delete all the float properties, use text-align: center applied to your #subnav. That will center all your inline-blocks included

Comment: I changed the ID to classes and it is still not lining up.  The `#subnav` div is adding extra space to the front of the first div and back of the last div.

Answer (score 0):

```
.subnavtab {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #A1CD3A;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Here is the full code : http://jsfiddle.net/7tjmZ/2/

Answer (score -1):

Use class name instead of id
and you can set the css properties using class name

Example:

```
.yourClassName
{
    background-color: #A1CD3A;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```